# PHP - Insert variable data to implode

Tags: php, mysql

This might be very basic for some of you but I really couldn't seem to figure it out @.@

I want to insert `$x` to this line: `(".implode(",",array_keys($data)).")`
and `$rid` to `$values = implode("','", array_values($data));`

Code:

```
if(count($data)){
    $x = "rid";
    $rid=$_SESSION['rid'];
    $values = implode("','", array_values($data));
    mysql_query("insert into appetizer (".implode(",",array_keys($data)).") values ('".$values."')");

    if(mysql_insert_id()) return mysql_insert_id();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I possibly do this?

Apologies to the noob question :3

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: We don't understand what you mean by "insert (variable) to (line of code)".  Could you back up a little and try to explain your goal - what *effect* do you want this code to have, that is not already happening?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to push those values and make it a key-pair value and dont mind any order, push assign it accordingly.

Push the value while its an array, then implode. No need making changes in the imploded string.

```
if(count($data) > 0){
    // key-pair values to be appended
    $x = "rid"; // the key
    $rid = $_SESSION['rid']; // the value

    $data[$x] = $rid; // just assign

    $values = implode("','", array_values($data));
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO appetizer (".implode(",",array_keys($data)).") values ('".$values."')");

    return mysql_insert_id();
}
```

I strongly suggest use a newer API, MySQLi or PDO instead.

```
if(count($data) > 0){
    // key-pair values to be appended
    $x = "rid"; // the key
    $rid = $_SESSION['rid']; // the value

    $data = array_merge(array($x => $rid), $data);

    $keys = array_keys($data);
    $values = array_values($data);

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO appetizer (' . implode(',', $keys) . ') VALUES (' . rtrim(str_repeat('?, ', count($keys)), ', ') . ')';

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name', 'username', 'password');
    $insert = $db->prepare($sql);
    $insert->execute($values);

    return $db->lastInsertId();
}
```

Sidenote: If you'd want the ID to be first, then another way could be used:

```
$data = array_merge(array($x => $rid), $data);
```

Comment: What if I want that value to be at the very first?

Comment: @serendipochi numerous ways, could merge or unshift